# Duda con Método .reduce en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gusto en saludarlos, me encuentro aprendiendo JavaScript, estoy pasando mis apuntes y me encontré con el siguiente código. Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Para qué sería ese ',0' al final de mi función 'usuariosOnline'?, de ante mano muchas gracias.

```
const usuarios = [
  {
    nombre: "usuario 1",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 2",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 3",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 4",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 5",
    enLinea: true,
  },
];

const usuariosOnline = usuarios.reduce((cont, usuario) => {
  if (usuario.enLinea) cont++; /* Sí es true aumenta el contador */
  return cont;
}, 0);

console.log(`Existen ${usuariosOnline} usuarios conectados`);
```

Comment: En general no usaría reduce para hacer eso en realidad, aunque lo entendería en caso académico. Lo que indica ese cero es el valor inicial, podrías probar ponerlo en 100 y verás que la cuenta comienza en ese valor. Si no se indica valor inicial toma como valor inicial el primer valor del array y lo saltea.
Link a documentación:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Comprendo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Supongo que es con fines académicos, debido a que es un curso que estoy siguiendo por YouTube. Para no quedar con la duda, ¿Cómo sería la forma correcta para poder llevar la cuenta de estos usuarios online?.

Comment: Es que se puede resolver con cualquier loop y un acumulador, que es lo que hace básicamente el Reduce..
No está mal usarlo, ni es incorrecto, pero no es muy amistoso para iniciar a aprender y quizás hay ejemplos que ayudan más a entender su funcionamiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis por tu tiempo, un saludo.

Comment: Siempre es un gusto Bastian, otro día serás tu ayudando a otros. 
Éxitos en este maravilloso mundo.

Answer (score 1):

El .reduce tienes parámetros obligatorios y opcionales.
En tu caso el '0', es el valor inicial por el cual comienza a contar.
Te darás cuenta que si le pones 1, en vez de ser 3 usuarios, serán 4.
Si le pones 5 por ejemplo, 5+3 = 8 usuarios.

**arr.reduce(callback(acumulador, valorActual[, índice[, array]])[, valorInicial])**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

El cero en tu función es el valor inicial del [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Creo que es más fácil compararlo con un for de toda la vida, así te puedes dar cuenta cómo funciona:

Ejemplo:

```js
const usuarios = [
  {
    nombre: "usuario 1",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 2",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 3",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 4",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 5",
    enLinea: true,
  },
];

const usuariosOnline = usuarios.reduce((cont, usuario) => {
  if (usuario.enLinea) cont++; /* Sí es true aumenta el contador */
  return cont;
}, 0);

function usuariosOnline2(){
  let cont=0; // este es el cero del reduce
  for(let usuario of usuarios)  // usuario es el mismo que usaruio del reduce 
  {
    if (usuario.enLinea) cont++;
  }
  return cont;
}

console.log(`Existen ${usuariosOnline} usuarios conectados`);
console.log(`Existen ${usuariosOnline2()} usuarios conectados`);
```

Pero no es necesario que sea un número puede ser cualquier cosa, pero debe ser del mismo tipo de dato que se quiere retornar. Tu querías retornar un número, por eso el cero es valido

Por ejemplo, queremos retornar la lista de usuarios, aquí pasamos un array vacío []

```js
const usuarios = [
  {
    nombre: "usuario 1",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 2",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 3",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 4",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 5",
    enLinea: true,
  },
];

const users = usuarios.reduce((cont, usuario) => {
  cont.push(usuario.nombre);
  return cont;
}, []);

console.log(users);
```

Ahora una lista de usuarios, pero que incluya siempre al usuario "Administrador" y a "Batman"

```js
const usuarios = [
  {
    nombre: "usuario 1",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 2",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 3",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 4",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 5",
    enLinea: true,
  },
];

const users = usuarios.reduce((cont, usuario) => {
  cont.push(usuario.nombre);
  return cont;
}, ["Administrador","Batman"]);

console.log(users);
```

Por otro lado, tambien podriamos querer que nos retornara un objeto, con dos propiedades

- online: cantidad de usuarios online
- offline: cantidad de usuarios offline

```js
const usuarios = [
  {
    nombre: "usuario 1",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 2",
    enLinea: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 3",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 4",
    enLinea: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "usuario 5",
    enLinea: true,
  },
];

const users = usuarios.reduce((cont, usuario) => {
  if(usuario.enLinea){
    cont.online++;
  }
  else{
    cont.offline++;
  }
  return cont;
}, {online:0, offline:0});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!